# The definition for column 'nvarchar' must include a data type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a cursor with an alter table command inside of it, which i want to use to create new columns in specific table. Columns names will contain values from one column from another table so thats why i used cursor to do this. Anyway i keep getting this error message: **Msg 173, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The definition for column 'nvarchar' must include a data type.** . Now i declared all datatypes (well i guess i did, i checked) and i can not figure otu why i keep getting this message. Couldn't find any simmilar problem on google so i decide to ask my first queston ever on this site. Hopeing for a quick answer. Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @rbr_param  nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @cName nvarchar(255)
SET @cName = 'P_'+@rbr_param+'_P'

DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT rbr_param FROM dbo.parametri_pomocna ORDER BY     rbr_param
OPEN curs
FETCH NEXT FROM curs
INTO @rbr_param
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

EXEC('ALTER TABLE dbo.Parametri ADD ' + @cName + ' nvarchar(255)')

FETCH NEXT FROM curs
INTO @rbr_param

END
CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs
```

Comment: I have a problem with your code.  You have it tagged as "mysql", but you are using `+` for string concatenation, as well as `exec()`.  Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: SQL Server... exciedently i added mysql tag. My bad

Comment: As a comment, never execute a dynamic SQL string directly. Assign it to a variable, then execute it: `exec sp_executesql @sql` Then if you have strange syntax errors, you can just `PRINT @sql` to see what the actual string being executed is.

Comment: ok thanx for the tips... and yes i accepted answer just had to waith 10 minutes for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@cName will not update automatically as the value of @rbr_param updates. You need to move this line

```
SET @cName = 'P_'+@rbr_param+'_P'
```

inside of the loop.

Comment: My pleasure, be sure to bear in mind these are scripting variables, it is more of a replacement model than the reference model you may be accustomed to.

Answer (score 1):

i think set the value after the fetch..

```
DECLARE @rbr_param  nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @cName nvarchar(255)

DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT rbr_param FROM dbo.parametri_pomocna ORDER BY     rbr_param
OPEN curs
FETCH NEXT FROM curs
INTO @rbr_param
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @cName = 'P_'+@rbr_param+'_P'

EXEC('ALTER TABLE dbo.Parametri ADD ' + @cName + ' nvarchar(255)')

FETCH NEXT FROM curs
INTO @rbr_param

END
CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs
```